# Extend lifetime of variable

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to return a slice from a vector which is built inside my function. Obviously this doesn't work because `v`'s lifetime expires too soon. I'm wondering if there's a way to extend `v`'s lifetime. I want to return a plain slice, not a vector.

```
pub fn find<'a>(&'a self, name: &str) -> &'a[&'a Element] {
    let v: Vec<&'a Element> = self.iter_elements().filter(|&elem| elem.name.borrow().local_name == name).collect();
    v.as_slice()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't forcibly extend a value's lifetime; you just have to return the full `Vec`. If I may ask, why do you want to return the slice itself? It is almost always unnecessary, since a `Vec` can be cheaply (both in the sense of easy syntax and low-overhead at runtime) coerced to a slice.

Alternatively, you could return the iterator:

```
use std::iter;

pub fn find<'a>(&'a self, name: &str) -> Box<Iterator<Item = &'a Element> + 'a> {
    Box::new(self.iter_elements()
       .filter(move |&elem| elem.name.borrow().local_name == name))
}
```

For now, you will have to use an iterator trait object, since closure have types that are unnameable.

NB. I had to change the `filter` closure to capture-by-move (the `move` keyword) to ensure that it can be returned, or else the `name` variable would just passed into the closure pointer into `find`'s stack frame, and hence would be restricted from leaving `find`.

Comment: I wanted to return a read-only list. I guess what I'd need is an OwnedSlice, but that's probably just Vec. I can't return an iterator, because I want it to be indexable.

Comment: Since the `Vec` (or whatever) contains `&Elements` the actual contents of the list is as read-only as it would be with a `&[]`. Returning a `Vec` rather than a `&[]` effectively just allows the user to modify the length of that vector (e.g. `push`/`pop` elements from it), restricting that is usually unnecessary especially in Rust, where `Vec`s etc. are uniquely owned, so changing a `Vec` doesn't change any values anywhere else.

Comment: Also, you can return an iterator: if the user absolutely needs to randomly-access it more than once, then they can manually `.collect()`. If they only wish to iterate in order, or index randomly once (possible via `nth`) then returning the iterator is likely to be more efficient, as the elements will only be generated on demand. Of course, if the structure is *usually* randomly-accessed, then requiring `collect` will just make things more verbose. (I just realised I made a mistake with the iterator suggestion as written. Fixing.)