# How can I iterate on a Bevy Query and keep a reference to the iterated value so that I can use it later?

Tags: rust, bevy

I have a borrow in the `empty` variable and I want to extend its life. In the commented code-block, I attempt to address it, but the reference is no longer available. I have to loop through the loop again to find the match in order to act on it.

How can I loop through a query looking for a best-match and then act on it once I know it's the best match, without having to loop through to find it again?

```
use bevy::prelude::*;

struct Person;
struct Name(String);

fn main() {
    App::build()
        .add_default_plugins()
        .add_startup_system(startup.system())
        .add_system(boot.system())
        .run();
}

fn boot(mut query: Query<(&Person, &mut Name)>) {
    let mut temp_str = String::new();
    let mut empty: Option<&mut Name> = None;
    for (_p, mut n_val) in &mut query.iter() {
        if n_val.0.to_lowercase() > temp_str.to_lowercase() {
            temp_str = n_val.0.clone();
            empty = Some(&mut n_val);
        }
    }
    println!("{}", temp_str);
    if let Some(n) = empty {
        // ...
    }
    // for (_p, mut n_val) in &mut query.iter() {
    //     if n_val.0 == temp_str {
    //         n_val.0 = "a".to_string();
    //     }
    // }
}

fn startup(mut commands: Commands) {
    commands
        .spawn((Person, Name("Gene".to_string())))
        .spawn((Person, Name("Candace".to_string())))
        .spawn((Person, Name("Zany".to_string())))
        .spawn((Person, Name("Sarah".to_string())))
        .spawn((Person, Name("Carl".to_string())))
        .spawn((Person, Name("Robert".to_string())));
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "sample"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
bevy = "0.1.3"
```

Specific error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:17:33
   |
17 |     for (_p, mut n_val) in &mut query.iter() {
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                                 |          |
   |                                 |          temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                                 creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
24 |     if let Some(n) = empty {
   |                      ----- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

error[E0597]: `n_val` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:26
   |
20 |             empty = Some(&mut n_val);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
21 |         }
22 |     }
   |     - `n_val` dropped here while still borrowed
23 |     println!("{}", temp_str);
24 |     if let Some(n) = empty {
   |                      ----- borrow later used here
```

Comment: I don't know anything about bevi, but can you try doing `let mut iter = query.iter(); for (_p, mut n_val) in &mut iter {`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You cannot extend the lifetime of a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28820781/155423), but that is not your issue here, the error says `temporary value dropped while borrowed`, so you must extend the lifetime of your temporary.

If you wonder what temporary, the compiler also points to that (literally) in the error message: `query.iter()`. This is a function call, and the returned value is not bound to anything, so the compiler creates a temporary value for that. Then you iterate using a reference to that temporary. When the `for` loop ends, the temporary is dropped and any reference lifetime to it expires.

The solution is to bind the temporary to a local variable. This way you extend the lifetime of the object to the scope of the variable:

```
let mut iter = query.iter();
for (_p, n_val) in &mut iter {
    if n_val.0.to_lowercase() > temp_str.to_lowercase() {
        temp_str = n_val.0.clone();
        empty = Some(n_val);
    }
}
```

PS: I find quite bizarre the pattern of iterating over `&mut iter`. I would expect the return of `iter()` to implement `Iterator` or `IntoIterator` directly, but it looks like [this is not the case](https://docs.rs/bevy_ecs/0.1.3/src/bevy_ecs/system/query.rs.html#169).

Comment: @VCD_WL: You are storing a reference to `n_val`, that is a variable local to the `for` loop, so it cannot escape that block. Try storing the `n_val` itself, that I think it is already a reference: `empty = Some(n_val);`.

Comment: That did it! Wow, I have some more learning to do here, but this gives me direction. Thank you!